# Wireless Speaker Pair that can play simultaneous audio from computer?

Tags: audio, wireless, speakers

At home, I frequently move between two rooms with my OS X laptop. I would like to get two wireless speakers and place one in each room, to avoid the hassle of having to connect them via Aux Line-in.

### Critical features:

The Wireless speakers I am looking for **should be able to source computer audio**, and let me select where to play it at any time:

- *Play one of the speakers*, or...
- *Both speakers at the same time*

Additionally, I would like them to:

- Support *AirPlay streaming* from iOS devices

### Optional features:

Optional, but not critical:

- Support direct streaming from services like Spotify, Soundcloud
- Allow Aux Line-In or equivalent
- Manufacturer also provides "bridge" unit that can connect ordinary line-in speakers to the Wi-Fi system

### Pricing:

Up to 450 USD per speaker, but preferably lower.
Audio quality should be **good** but doesn't need to be ***Hi-Fi great*** (and thus very expensive).

---

Because of the above criteria, I'm assuming that Bluetooth speakers are not effective, because I need to be able to move around with the laptop and still have connectivity. Also, there is a thick wall between the two rooms so they wouldn't be able to communicate with each other via Bluetooth.

So my question is if you could recommend some Wi-Fi speakers that meet these critera – if there are any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original Hi-Fi Wi-Fi speaker company, [Sonos](https://www.sonos.com), seems to be your fit. They have three product lines that are **fully inter-operable** with each other; in order of increasing quality (and obviously price): [the Play 1, 3 and 5](http://www.sonos.com/products/wireless-speakers) at $200, $300 and $500 respectively.

Despite the $50 budget breach per speaker, I include the Play 5 because you'll need at least one (or the CONNECT or the CONNECT AMP) *for full source computer (Apple) audio* (i.e. sources from non-Sonos compatible streaming apps). The Play 5 is also the only one with an AUX, the biggest speaker and as I mentioned the speakers are fully inter-operable, so you can mix and match.

As long as you have at least one Play 5/CONNECT/CONNECT AMP connected to an AirPort Express, all models ***exceed*** your critical requirements:

> Critical features:
>
> The Wireless speakers I am looking for should be able to source 
>   computer audio, and let me select where to play it at any time *(yes for Apple devices via AirPlay)*:
>
> - Play one of the speakers, or...
> - Both speakers at the same time *(2 speakers be can linked for great stereo output)*
>
>   - *additional speakers can all play at the same time*
>   - *all speakers can be divided and grouped individually into zones playing different music. Note: if using AirPlay, group functions are still available, however AirPlay is treated by Sonas a single source-so same music only in that group*
>
> Additionally, I would like them to:
>
> [Support AirPlay streaming from iOS devices](https://sonos.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1241#5)

And satisfy almost all optional features:

> - Support direct streaming from services like Spotify [(*with Spotify premium-yes*)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTyWKvwrHs0), Soundcloud *(not sure-but if it plays through AirPlay then yes)*
> - Allow Aux Line-In or equivalent (*Play 5 only*)
> - Manufacturer also provides [*"bridge"*](http://www.sonos.com/products/wireless-stereo-components) unit that can connect ordinary line-in speakers to the Wi-Fi system

Now in contrast to previous Sonos speakers, the latest ones connect directly to your Wi-Fi and don't require the old $50 bridge. Assuming a total budget of $900 for any 2 speakers and that you have an AirPort Express (additional $100 if you don't), to stay within it you could get (in order of preference):

1. (1 x Play 5) + (1 x Play 3) = $800
2. (1 x Connect) + (1 x Play 3) + (1 x Play 1) = $850

I'd go with option 1 myself because it's more than enough my for average (European) place. All the Plays sound amazing, but obviously the Play 5 **really** fills the room, so put plug that in your bigger/more frequented room with the AirPort Express [next to it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8F-6HwuHGs8). If you don't have an AirPort Express you can get one and still be in your $900 budget.

If you want to fill a large house, stretch the budget and get 2 Play 5s. Or buy 1 Play 5, test it and decide on another or a Play 3. The main lady will try, but she'll never keep you down.

Comment: Also, while having great apps for Android and iOS Wi-Fi speakers (that also had bluetooth) from [Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/us/video/multi-room) and [Denon](https://usa.denon.com/us/wireless-multi-room-music-system) (which also had AUX in for all models and an optional battery for the HEOS 1) don't seem to have great desktop OS X/Windows functionality-if any.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! I had considered the Sonos line-up, but I couldn't confirm that they can in fact source computer audio to both speakers at the same time. See [this](https://en.community.sonos.com/music-services-and-sources-228994/computer-as-sonos-audio-source-4465896/index13.html) and [this](https://en.community.sonos.com/wireless-speakers-228992/why-wont-sonos-allow-wireless-audio-streaming-for-movies-from-macpc-6449321) thread that it can't be done. Maybe the software changed recently or there's something I'm missing. Can you confirm that Sonos can source from OS X via Wifi?

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant streaming audio from a computer (OS X) via Sonos compatible apps e.g. iTunes, Spotify etc. You mean full audio from your computer (or phone/tablet) e.g. streamin audio from a downloaded movie on any app. **From what I understand, for Apple devices, the very quick answer seems to be yes via [AirPlay](https://sonos.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1241#5)**-for which you'll need at least one Play 5 (or CONNECT or CONNECT AMP) & Airport Express, have a scroll down to the questions section

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I'm probably going to get a Sonos solution. I just have to make sure that streaming to two speakers at the same time works via Airplay from a OS X Computer (hopefully it does). Airplay is a pretty robust solution, perhaps the outcry in the linked forums thread concern Windows and other operating systems.

Comment: With your AirPlay device(s) connected to your OS X computer, you'd go to System Preferences-Sound-Output tab and select the AirPlay device connected to the Sonos. You *should* then get full audio transfer. You'll have normal Sonos features like grouping multiple speakers. This is in addition to the Sonos to AirPlay connection linked above.

Comment: Can this play video games?

Comment: @JimThio The Play 5 has an aux in, so it can play anything from a headphone jack. For example the PS4 controller has a headphone jack you can use to output all sound.

Comment: I mean PC dekstop computer. Can PC Desktop transmit wifi audio to these speakers.

Comment: @JimThio The quick answer would be no, not easily. You'd need to find third party software to stream non-compatible applications like games. Or more simply, connect at least one Play 5/CONNECT/CONNECT AMP to the pc via AUX then any other speakers in the network will wirelessly stream that AUX input.